# Android get leaderboard name from google play services programatically

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I see this https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/Leaderboard and: getDisplayName()
Retrieves the display name of this leaderboard.

How do I "get" the leaderboard using the leaderboard id to call this method? Is there an example of this somewhere? Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and [mcve] for asking better received questions. Please provide some code so people can see were you went wrong or that you actually tried to do it yourself first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Leaderboard reference](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/Leaderboard) in the docs only state [getDisplayName ()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/Leaderboard.html#getDisplayName()) as a means to retrieve the display name of the leaderboard. It does not mention a built-in function using the leaderboard id.

A sample usage of this is found in [this tutorial](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=PlayGames-master/src/android/com/anyks/playgames/playgamesutils/PlayGamesServices.java):

```
Leaderboard leaderboard = loadScoresResult 
.getLeaderboard(); 
String leaderboardName = leaderboard.getDisplayName() ;
```